# assign the value of a command to a variable in linux

Tags: r, linux

I am working in R that invokes linux commands.
This is my code:

```
system2("wc", args = c("-l",(paste0(" ", file1),stdout = TRUE))
```

I need to save the word count value to a variable and call it in R. How can I do that?

Comment: WC = system2("wc", args = c("-l",(paste0(" ", file1),stdout = TRUE))    ?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems to be correct, but check your parentheses:

```
file1 <- tempfile()
cat("There are seven words in this sentence.", file = file1)
count <- system2("wc", args = c("-w", file1), stdout = TRUE)
as.numeric(sub(file1, "", count))
# [1] 7
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. It gave a 0 while the actual value is 2993. Could you suggest something?

Comment: Please include a minimal working example in your question that reproduces your problem.

Comment: when I run the Rscript, system2("wc", args = c("-l",(paste0(" ", file1),stdout = TRUE)) printed 2993 without a print command. But I need to call this value later in my code. So, when I tried to save this value to a variable, expected<- system2("wc", args = c("-w", file1), stdout = TRUE) and print it, it printed it as zero.

Comment: Change the `"-w"` to `"-l"`?

Comment: I need the line count of the file so can I still do that?